# how to create custom modules in joomla?

Tags: joomla

Here am created a small project with my own framework in php, but i need to convert that php project to joomla module.

Comment: Create your project to a Joomla module? You do not seem to be familiar with Joomlas naming. You are probably looking into converting it into a component, and not just a module. A module is a display-part. Components are the bigger extension mechanisms. But I can’t really tell without more info …

Comment: am planning to use wrapper in module. any more ideas other than this.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

http://developer.joomla.org/getting-started.html

http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial:Creating_a_Hello_World_Module_for_Joomla_1.5

(And next time google a bit first.)

Answer (score 0):

Create your project to a Joomla module? You do not seem to be familiar with Joomlas naming. You are probably looking into converting it into a component, and not just a module. A module is a display-part. Components are the bigger extension mechanisms. But I can’t really tell without more info …

The [Joomla docs for developers](http://docs.joomla.org/Developers) include several guides, descriptions and tutorials.

[For Modules](http://docs.joomla.org/Module_Development). Amongst them:

- [Creating a Hello World Module for Joomla 1.5](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Hello_World_Module_for_Joomla_1.5)
- [Creating a simple module](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_simple_module)

[For Components](http://docs.joomla.org/Component_Development).

As you seem to be familiar with PHP and frameworks, just peeking into existing modules and components may be just as effective (at first).